# Issue with duplicate key update with existing values?

Tags: mysql

I have a DB table that already has an existing value that I don't need to touch.  When I try to call my SQL like so:

my table currently looks like this:

```
id  col1 col2
5   10
```

$sql = "INSERT INTO sometable (id, col2) VALUES (5, 20)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = 5";

I would expect the table to look like this after my insert:

```
id  col1 col2
5   10   20
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without using an update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming id is the key

This

```
INSERT INTO sometable (id, col2) VALUES (5, 20) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = 5
```

Says to update the id field  to 5 (`UPDATE ID =5`). Which would only work if the ID was 5 and makes no sense

What you want is either

```
INSERT INTO sometable (id, col2) VALUES (5, 20) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2 = 20;
```

Or if you want to reference the value it would have been if there was no duplicate then use as [Wilken suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11057226/119477) `COL2 = VALUES(COl2)`

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90b1a/1)

Comment: great example but my query still complains about the second column (col1) doesn't have a default value...

Comment: @Paul oh you didn't say that in your original question. If col1 is non -nullable and doesn't have a default specified the `INSERT` portion won't work if you don't include it in the column list. Do you really want to do an insert? What should the value be for col1 if you do want to insert?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`VALUES()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values)

```
INSERT INTO sometable (id, col2) VALUES (5, 20)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2 = VALUES(col2);
```

Comment: +1.  (I usually mess up the syntax by trying to include a `SET` keyword, and have to look at the documentation again.)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out for a good example:
[MySQL: Insert On Duplicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)